# What is the pose topic move_base subscribes to?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

move_base extracts the current position from tf. what is the name of the frame it subscribes to relative to /map frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223208/what-is-the-pose-topic-move_base-subscribes-to?/) by [Shams](https://answers.ros.org/users/2251/shams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`move_base` actually gets the current position from the costmap (see [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/move_base/html/move__base_8cpp_source.html#l00462)).

Thus, you specify the the `frame_id` in the costmap config file via the `~<name>/robot_base_frame` parameter, which defaults to `base_link`.

As you write correctly, it uses tf to get the current position, so it does not subscribe to a topic other than `tf` for this.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0